# Latitude 7430 does not detect intel graphics card (choking)

Tags: graphics, dell, intel, 22.10

This week I installed ubuntu 22.10 in my latitude 7430 which is supported ubuntu hardware but, it does not load the intel driver for my graphics card AND the video "chokes/freezes" every few seconds. What can I do?

```
~> sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:176 memory:6054000000-6054ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

Comment: It shows driver=i915, so Intel driver is loaded. Is issue then something else?

Comment: you can try adding nomodeset to grub. By the way, this is the worse laptop ever for Linux. HDMI and USB-C video outputs are not working, display brightness adjustment is not working. Display rotation (even manual) if you want to use the tablet is not working. The only thing that I got working is the fingerprint.

Comment: @oldfred so the problem is that the i915 doesn't work well. I get glitches in my screen every now and then and even playing videos is troublesome; videos just stop/break randomly.

Comment: @maxadamo adding nomodeset disables brightness control which is a no go for me (bad eyesight), so had to remove it. Trying out acpi_osi=linux

Comment: Do not know if this applies to you or not. Often fixes for newest chips also help several generations back, also. https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-New-Xe-Linux-Driver  I have motherboard with i5-12400 and have no issues with Kubuntu 22.04. I have booted with 22.10 but not really used it. My chip is not the top end model and shows video as  Device: Mesa Intel(R) Graphics (ADL-S GT1) (0x4692) Version: 22.0.5  Typically very newest hardware takes a while for Linux kernel & drivers to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i had the same issue as you.

I think this is related to https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/7623

If you use Ubuntu 22.04 and do not install any updates, so that you are using the Kernel 5.15 kernel, you will be ok, everything seems to be working normally for me, except the touch screen which I am not sure my laptop even supports or not.